# Обрезка ссылки до нужных данных Python

Tags: python

У меня есть ссылка по типу: https://example.com/example/example/FIFA/1939256-FIFA18-Penalty/322917680-Real-Madrid-Barcelona/

Мне нужно обрезать эту ссылку чтобы остались вот эти цифры -> 322917680

Обратить это всё в список и получать всё по индексу не выйдет потому, что ссылка меняется ежедневно и вместо https://example.com/ может быть https://example-123.com/ поэтому получится смещение и это не подходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это легко сделать с помощью регулярных выражений.

```
import re

s = 'https://example.com/example/example/FIFA/1939256-FIFA18-Penalty/322917680-Real-Madrid-Barcelona/'

result = re.findall( r'^.*/(\d*)-Real-Madrid-Barcelon', s)

value = result[0]
```

Функция `re.findall` найдёт в строке все подходящие подстроки и вернёт в виде списка. В переменную `value` сохраняем первый элемент из возвращённых, так как мы ищем лишь одно значение и будет найдено лишь одно.

Если вдруг понадобится вытаскивать обе цифры, то изменяем шаблон регулярного выражения на такой: `result = re.findall( r'/(\d*)-', s)`

Теперь в `result` лежит такой список: `['1939256', '322917680']`

Comment: забыл написать что -Real-Madrid-Barcelon меняется к примеру на -Paris-Saint-Germain-Bayern, и заменять всё это в ручную каждую минуту не очень удобно, как быть?

Comment: Как я написал ниже, используй второй шаблон `result = re.findall( r'/(\d*)-', s)` и из списка `result` вытаскивай второе число - это будет оно: `result[1]`

Answer (score 3):

Также кроме `re` можно сделать так:

```py
link = 'https://example.com/example/example/FIFA/1939256-FIFA18-Penalty/322917680-Real-Madrid-Barcelona/'
last_crumb = link.removesuffix('/').split('/')[-1]
print(last_crumb)
# 322917680-Real-Madrid-Barcelona
```

А дальше можно

```py
last_crumb[:9]  # '322917680'
last_crumb.split('-')[0]  # '322917680'
```

Comment: там вместо -Real-Madrid-Barcelona может быть к примеру -Paris-Saint-Germain-Bayern

Comment: Неважно, у вас берётся последнее значение после `/`, а затем либо первые 9 символов (если идшник всегда 9 цифр), либо всё до первого `-`

Comment: спасибо за вариант

Answer (score 3):

Или можно так

```
s = 'https://example.com/example/example/FIFA/1939256-FIFA18-Penalty/322917680-Real-Madrid-Barcelona/'
print(s[:-1].split('/')[-1].split('-')[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
from urllib import parse
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://example.com/example/example/FIFA/1939256-FIFA18-Penalty/322917680-Real-Madrid-Barcelona/'
    url_path = parse.urlparse(url).path
    path = Path(url_path)
    print(path.name.split('-')[0])
```